# Trigonometry Equation Doesn't Work With Input Variables

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I am using Trigonometry to move an object across the screen, for some reason the "x1" works but the "y1" does not unless the values are `x1 = 200;` `y1 = 200;`

I know that it is a problem with the equation and not something else.

Constructor:

```
public Note_1(double x0,double y0,double x1,double y1,
              double x2,double y2){
    sX = x0;sY = y0;img_1x = x1;img_1y = y1;
    img_2x = x2;img_2y = y2;
}
```

Methods Used:

```
public static double getAmp(double sx,double fx){
    double amp = (fx-sx)/2;
    return amp;
}
public static double getPeriod(double sx,double fx){
    double period = 360/(fx-sx);
    return period;
}
public static double getYDistplace(double sy,double fy){
    double yDisplace = (sy+fy)/2;
    return yDisplace;
}
```

Calculation Code:

```
@Override
protected void setup(){
    a = getAmp(sX,img_2x);
    period = getPeriod(sX,img_2x);
    yDist = getYDisplace(sY,img_2y);
}
@Override
protected void calculate(){
    obj.setX(obj.getX()+2);
    img_x1 = obj.getX();
    obj.setY(a*Math.cos(period*(img_x1+sX)/100)+yDist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.sin` and `Math.cos` work in radians, but I see you dividing quantities by 360. Perhaps this is an issue involving degrees and radians?

Comment: you were right about it being an issue involving radians, turns out `period` was screwing up the calculations. The correct calculation for period is `Math.toRadians((360/(fx-sx))+(2*Math.PI));`